# WP Job Manager plugin - Listing only the twelve job categories on frontpage order by jobs they have

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

i am using wp job manager plugin and i am trying to list on the frontpage only the twelve job categories according to the jobs they having. The job categories having more jobs go first. I managed to list the job categories with the above code but the problem is that the sorting and the number of categories not working as i expected. Any suggestions?

```
<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',] ), true ) . '</pre>'; ?>

    <?php  echo '<ul class="job-category-list">'; ?>
                <?php foreach ( get_terms( array(
                                          'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
                                         ) ) as $cat): 
                ?>
           <?php  $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                                            'post_type'      => 'job_listing',
                                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                                            'posts_per_page' => '12',
                                            'orderby'        => 'tag_count',
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                             array(
                                                  'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
                                                  'field'    => 'term_id',
                                                  'terms'    => $cat->term_id
                                                              )
                                                 )
                                            ) );
                 $count = $the_query->found_posts;
            ?>   
               <?php echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($cat).'" title="'.esc_attr($cat->name).'">'.$cat->name.'</a>&nbsp;('.( $count ).')</li>'; 

            ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php echo '</ul>'; ?>`
```

The output from `get_terms()`:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 3178
                [name] => Αγορές / Προμήθεις
                [slug] => agores-promithies
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 3168
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 7
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [1] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1125
                [name] => Αγροτικά
                [slug] => agrotika
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 126
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 7
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [2] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1127
                [name] => Αερομεταφορές
                [slug] => aerometafores
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 127
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 2
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [3] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1128
                [name] => Αισθητική / Κομμωτήρια
                [slug] => aisthitiki-komotiria
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 128
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 15
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [4] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1130
                [name] => Ανθρώπινοι Πόροι
                [slug] => antropinoi-poroi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 129
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 18
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [5] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1129
                [name] => Ανώτατη Διοίκηση
                [slug] => anotati-dioikisi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 130
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 13
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [6] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1131
                [name] => Αποθήκη / Logistics
                [slug] => logistics
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 131
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 44
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [7] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1132
                [name] => Ασφάλειες
                [slug] => asfaleies
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 132
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 2
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [8] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1133
                [name] => Γραμματειακή Υποστήριξη
                [slug] => secretary
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 133
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 85
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [9] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1135
                [name] => Δημιουργικό Τμήμα / Γραφίστες
                [slug] => dimiourgiko-tmima
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 134
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 16
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [10] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1134
                [name] => Δημόσιες Σχέσεις
                [slug] => dimosies-sxeseis
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 135
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 14
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [11] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1136
                [name] => Δημοσιογράφοι / Μ.Μ.Ε.
                [slug] => dimosiografoi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 136
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 11
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [12] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1137
                [name] => Διαφήμιση / Promotion
                [slug] => diafimisi-promotion
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 137
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 21
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [13] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1138
                [name] => Διαχείριση Ποιότητας
                [slug] => diaxeirisi-poiotitas
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 138
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 10
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [14] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1139
                [name] => Διοίκηση Επιχειρήσεων
                [slug] => dioikisi-epixeiriseon
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 139
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 16
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [15] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1140
                [name] => Εθελοντικές Εργασίες
                [slug] => ethelontikes-ergasies
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 140
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 8
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [16] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1141
                [name] => Εκπαιδευτικοί
                [slug] => ekpedeutikoi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 141
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 52
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [17] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1166
                [name] => Εξυπηρέτηση Πελατών / Call Center
                [slug] => call-center
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 142
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 30
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [18] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1168
                [name] => Εξωτερικές Εργασίες / Security
                [slug] => security
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 143
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 13
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [19] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1142
                [name] => Επαγγέλματας Υγείας
                [slug] => epagelmata-ygeias
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 145
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 43
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [20] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1143
                [name] => Επιστήμες
                [slug] => epistimes
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 146
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 20
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [21] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1144
                [name] => Επιχειρηματικότητα
                [slug] => epixeirimatikotita
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 147
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 6
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [22] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1338
                [name] => Εστιατόρια / Καφέ
                [slug] => estiatoria-cafe
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 1340
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 96
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [23] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1145
                [name] => Καταστήματα Λιανικής
                [slug] => katastimata-lianikis
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 148
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 30
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [24] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1146
                [name] => Λογιστήριο
                [slug] => logistirio
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 149
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 23
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [25] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1147
                [name] => Μάρκετινγκ
                [slug] => marketing
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 150
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 23
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [26] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1148
                [name] => Μεστικά
                [slug] => mesitika
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 151
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 4
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [27] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1149
                [name] => Μεταφορές
                [slug] => metafores
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 152
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 31
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [28] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1150
                [name] => Μηχανικοί
                [slug] => mixanikoi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 153
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 50
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [29] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1151
                [name] => Ναυτιλιακά
                [slug] => nautiliaka
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 154
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 6
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [30] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1152
                [name] => Νομικό Τμήμα
                [slug] => nomiko-tmima
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 155
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 6
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [31] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1165
                [name] => Οδηγοί
                [slug] => odigoi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 156
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 40
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [32] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1167
                [name] => Οικιακοί Βοηθοί
                [slug] => oikiakoi-voithoi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 157
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 11
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [33] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1153
                [name] => Περιβάλλον
                [slug] => perivalon
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 158
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 6
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [34] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1154
                [name] => Πληροφορική
                [slug] => pliroforiki
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 159
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 28
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [35] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1155
                [name] => Πολιτιστικά / Τέχνες
                [slug] => politistika-texnes
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 160
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 12
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [36] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1156
                [name] => Πωλήσεις
                [slug] => poliseis
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 161
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 84
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [37] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1157
                [name] => Σύμβουλοι Επιχειρήσεων
                [slug] => symvouloi-epixeiriseon
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 162
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 9
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [38] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1158
                [name] => Τεχνικοί / Συντηρητές
                [slug] => texnikoi-syntirites
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 163
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 32
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [39] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1159
                [name] => Τηλεπικοινωνίες
                [slug] => tilepikoinonies
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 164
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 6
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [40] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1160
                [name] => Τομέας Παραγωγής
                [slug] => tomeas-paragogis
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 165
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 21
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [41] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1161
                [name] => Τουρισμός / Ξενοδοχεία
                [slug] => tourismos-hotels
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 166
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 84
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [42] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1162
                [name] => Τράπεζες
                [slug] => trapezes
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 167
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 9
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [43] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1164
                [name] => Υποστηρικτικοί Υπάλληλοι
                [slug] => ypostiriktikoi-ypaliloi
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 168
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 63
                [filter] => raw
            )

        [44] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 1163
                [name] => Χρηματοοικονομικά
                [slug] => xrimatooikonomika
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 169
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_category
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 14
                [filter] => raw
            )

    )
```

Comment: You have job categories and you want the categories ordered by the number of jobs per category?

Comment: Yes exactly. Ι have job categories and i want to order them according to the number of jobs that they having.

Comment: dear panos dear disinfor - many thanks for this great idea - perhaps this is a great contribution for the snippet collection - see link below https://wpjobmanager.com/customization-snippets/

This page consists of all the customization snippets we have so far. We may occasionally add new ones and we encourage everyone to also send their own snippets to us! If you add a customization that you think will benefit others, get in touch with the guys at https://wpjobmanager.com/customization-snippets/
have a great  day

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

This is a much simpler version of what you are looking to do. You don't need `WP_Query()`. You can use a `foreach` loop and an iterator:

```
<?php
echo '<ul class="job-category-list">';

// Get the terms and order them by count in descending order.
$terms = get_terms( [
        'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
        'orderby'  => 'count',
        'order'    => 'DESC',
    ]
);

// Set an iterator
$i = 1;
// foreach term
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // if the iterator is less than or equal to 12.
    if ( $i <= 12 ) :
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>&nbsp;(' . ( $term->count ) . ')</li>';
        // Increase the iterator.
        $i++;
    endif;
}

echo '<ul><!-- /job-category-list -->';
?>
```

For the count, not sure why are you seeing a difference. But this essentially gives you what you want.

EDIT: from this wpse post: [List taxonomy / category count showing list published posts only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284022/list-taxonomy-category-count-showing-list-published-posts-only)

You can use this filter to get the correct count for only published posts:

```
function get_terms_filter_published( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $taxonomy = $taxonomies[0];
  if ( ! is_array($terms) && count($terms) < 1 ) {
    return $terms;
  }

  $filtered_terms = array();
  $ctr = 0;
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts p JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships rl ON p.ID = rl.object_id WHERE rl.term_taxonomy_id = $term->term_id AND p.post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 1");
    $published_terms[ $ctr ] = $term;
    if ( intval($result) > 0 ) {
        $published_terms[ $ctr ] = $term;
    } else {
        // you can comment this out if you don't want to show empty terms
        $published_terms[ $ctr ]->count = 0;
    }
    $ctr++;
  }
  return $published_terms;
}

add_filter('get_terms', 'get_terms_filter_published', 10, 3);
```

So, add that filter function to your functions.php and use the code above to get what you want - only the first 12 categories based on post count.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your suggestions. The new lines added didn't do the work as we expected. Instead of this:ex  technology(10) logistics(9) Economy (6) we have:Economy(5), Economy(10), Economy(4), Economy(7).

Comment: In the code you have, please update your question with the output of this `<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',] ), true ) . '</pre>';` I want to see what data you're actually working with. Put this line of code before any of the other code.

Comment: I update  my question as you suggest. Also it seems that  'posts_per_page' => '12' not working either

Comment: Please post what outputs in your web browser from that code I gave you. You didn't need to add it to the question. I want to know what returns for your `get_terms()`.

Comment: I post it below so you can see what is the output

Comment: I edited your question to add the code output. You can delete the answer.

Comment: What I notice is that the count in the WP_Term Object is not the same with the jobs in the frontend ot the website. Ex: [slug] => tourismos-hotels [count] => 84 but in the frontend the jobs are 39 which is the correct

Comment: I updated the code to correctly output what is in your WP_Term_Object. However, I'm not sure why you are using `WP_Query()` since your original code isn't outputting any posts associated with those categories. If you are just outputting the category names, you can remove everything from my comment `// Not sure...` through `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: I remove the code frrom your comment as you suggest. It seems that the posts_per_page' => '12' not working as i want only twelve categories listed not all of them. Also the WP_Term_Object count is not correct as i mentioned above. When using WP_Query() the $count = $the_query->found_posts; output the correct count

Comment: `posts_per_page` doesn't work like that. That limits the number of posts attached to a category. Do you have draft jobs, unpublished jobs that are assigned to those categories? I can't really help with counts are that incorrect. If you look in the `job_listing_taxonomy` edit page (Job Listing). Are the counts wrong there too?

Comment: No the counts are correct in the `job_listing_taxonomy` page. Yes i have draft jobs maybe this is the issue. I also try with the `post_status =>'publish' `but not working either.

Comment: Using the WP Query isn't going to get you what you want. `'post_status' => 'publish'` is for quering POSTS not the taxonomies. I updated my answer which should get you closer.

Comment: I have been added the function but didn't correct the counts. I don't know why. I am using WP Query because as you can see in my question the counts works fine.

Comment: dear panos dear disinfor - many thanks for this great idea - perhaps this is a great contribution for the snippet collection - see link below https://wpjobmanager.com/customization-snippets/

This page consists of all the customization snippets we have so far. We may occasionally add new ones and we encourage everyone to also send their own snippets to us! If you add a customization that you think will benefit others, get in touch with the guys at https://wpjobmanager.com/customization-snippets/
have a great  day